The Flutter app initiated by a deep link fails to navigate initially, but it works perfectly when using the back button after the app restarts
I'm using Branch for deep link management in my Flutter app.
On iOS, everything works perfectly.
On Android, when I open the application from a deep link (e.g., from WhatsApp), the app opens but doesn't receive any link. If I return to WhatsApp without pressing the back button but by navigating from the recent apps, it still doesn't work. However, if I open it from WhatsApp and then press the device's back button, it takes me back to WhatsApp, and from that moment on, the links start working without any issues.
If I manually launch the app (not through a link), go to WhatsApp, and click the link, it takes me to the app, but the link isn't received. If I now go to WhatsApp through the recent apps and click the link again, it still doesn't work; it only opens the app without receiving the link. However, if I click back with the app open, it takes me back to WhatsApp, and now clicking the link works, and it continues to work from that moment on.
Android Manifest Activity:
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true" android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      <!-- Branch URI Scheme -->
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <data android:scheme="..."/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      </intent-filter>

      <!-- Branch App Links - Live App -->
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="....app.link"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="...-alternate.app.link"/>
      </intent-filter>

...
Flutter Doctor Output:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.3, on macOS 14.4 23E214 darwin-arm64, locale it-IT)
• Flutter version 3.19.3 on channel stable at /Users/dev/FlutterDev/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision ba39319843 (4 weeks ago), 2024-03-07 15:22:21 -0600
• Engine revision 2e4ba9c6fb
• Dart version 3.3.1
• DevTools version 2.31.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
• Android SDK at /Users/dev/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-34, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+0-17.0.9b1087.7-11185874)
• All Android licenses accepted.

• No issues found!

I tried changing the launchMode to singleTop, but it opens the link multiple times and creates another instance on WhatsApp. I also tried adding 'android:allowTaskReparenting="true", 'android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"' and singleInstance & standard, but it didn't work.
